# Filter makefile prerequisites

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Given a Makefile prerequisite

```
PY_FILES := $(shell find . -type f -name *.py)

my_target: $(PY_FILES)
  do_something $(PY_FILES)
```

Is it possible to call `do_something` on a subset of it i.e. exclude all the python files that match a pattern e.g. `*/test/*`?

My understanding is that `$(filter-out pattern, text)` can do something similar, but pattern has to be a list of files that I want to exclude.

In that case I could as well `find` with `-not` and save the result to another prerequisite which is what I am trying to avoid – I want to reuse the `PY_FILES` prereq.

Comment: `pattern` has to be a *pattern* that matches files you want to exclude. Unfortunately make patterns only support a single wildcard element so you can't `$(filter-out)` a pattern that matches `*/test/*` easily. You *can* ignore those with `find` easily though as you indicated.

Answer (score 0):

There's not good built-in way to match a `*/test/*` style pattern with make built-ins. The pattern matching just isn't that sophisticated.

You could try something like this but splitting the files at `find` time is likely going to perform better and be more useful in the end.

```
define testfilter
    $(foreach f,$1,$(if $(findstring /test/,$f),,$f))
endef

my_target: $(PY_FILES)
        do_something $(call testfilter,$(PY_FILES))
```

Comment: @ComeRaczy Thanks for the poke on that but using `$(if)` is simpler than re-filtering.